# Restart interval after clearinterval in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to resume SetInterval after clearinterval? my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        var ao =$('ul').hasClass('slides');
        if(ao==true){
            var detik = -1345; 
            var time = setInterval(function(){
                detik+=0.5;
                $('.slides').attr("style","width: "+oke+"px; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d("+detik+"px, 0px, 0px);");
                    if (detik > 0  ){
                         detik = -1345;
                    }
                }, 1);

            $('.flex-prev, .flex-next').on('click',function(){
                clearInterval(time);
            });            
        }
    },3000);

});
```

Comment: by assigning the result of the same call to setInterval again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - How to restart setInterval after killing it off with clearInterval?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986667/jquery-how-to-restart-setinterval-after-killing-it-off-with-clearinterval)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function for your `setInterval()`. you can just call the `startInterval()` function for restart your timer;

```
var detik = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        var ao =$('ul').hasClass('slides');
        if(ao==true){
            detik = -1345; 
            startInterval();
            $('.flex-prev, .flex-next').on('click',function(){
                clearInterval(time);
            });            
        }
    },3000);

    function startInterval(){
        time = setInterval(function(){
            detik+=0.5;
            $('.slides').attr("style","width: "+oke+"px; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d("+detik+"px, 0px, 0px);");
            if (detik > 0  ){
                 detik = -1345;
            }
        }, 1);
    }

});
```